# Rsync doesn't recognize locale

Tags: rsync

I try to sync two Ububntu machines throgh Rsync. When I execute:

```
rsync -rv -p 2222 --progress --delete-before --ignore-existing andrew@192.168.0.101:/media/Maindata/Книги/ /media/Maindata/Книги
```

I got:

```
Unexpected remote arg: andrew@192.168.0.101:/media/Maindata/\#320\#232\#320\#275\#320\#270\#320\#263\#320\#270/
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.1]
```

After executing **locale** at my andrew@192.168.0.101 machine outpus is like this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_UA.UTF-8
```

But, when i do it from client:

```
    ssh -p 2222 andrew@192.168.0.101 locale
```

*LANGUAGE* env var have disappeared:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_UA.UTF-8
```

Is it can be my problem with locale? Or maybe something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

rsync -rv -p 2222 --progress --delete-before --ignore-existing **--iconv=iso639-2,iso8859-1** andrew@192.168.0.101:/media/Maindata/Книги/ /media/Maindata/Книги

or

rsync -rv -p 2222 --progress --delete-before --ignore-existing **--iconv=iso8859-1,iso639-2** andrew@192.168.0.101:/media/Maindata/Книги/ /media/Maindata/Книги